# jQuery Validation not working

Tags: jquery, validation

Any ideas why this code doesn't work?

```
var newpost_validator = {};
var editpost_validator = {};

var newupload_validator = {};
var editupload_validator = {};

var newquestion_validator = {};
var editquestion_validator = {};

var comment_validator = {};

$(function()
{
    newpost_validator = $("#newpostform").validate({
        rules: {
            post_title: "required",
            post_url:  {
                required: {
                    depends: function() {
                        return $('input[name=post_category]:checked').val() == '14';
                    }
                },
                url: true
            },
            post_code: {
                required: {
                    depends: function() {
                        return $('input[name=post_category]:checked').val() == '13';
                    }
                }
            },
            post_content: "required",
            post_tags: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            post_title: "Your post MUST have a title",
            post_url: "Please enter a valid URL, don't forget the http://",
            post_code: "Please add your code",
            post_content: "Your post MUST have some content",
            post_tags: "Please add some tags"
        }
    });

    editpost_validator = $("#editpostform").validate({
        rules: {
            post_title: "required",
            post_content: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            post_title: "Please enter a title",
            post_content: "Please enter the content"
        }
    });

    newquestion_validator = $("#newquestionform").validate({
        rules: {
            post_title: "required",
            post_content: "required",
            post_tags: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            post_title: "Please enter a title",
            post_content: "Please enter the content",
            post_tags: "Please enter some tags"
        }
    });

    editquestion_validator = $("#editquestionform").validate({
        rules: {
            post_title: "required",
            post_content: "required"
        },                          },
        messages: {
            post_title: "Please enter a title",
            post_content: "Please enter the content"
        }
    });

    newupload_validator = $("#newuploadform").validate({
        rules: {
            post_title: "required",
            post_upload: {
                  required: true,
                  accept: "jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|png"
                },
            post_content: "required",
            post_tags: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            post_title: "Please enter a title",
            post_upload: "Please upload a valid image file",
            post_content: "Please enter the content",
            post_tags: "Please enter some tags"
        }
    });

    editupload_validator = $("#edituploadform").validate({
        rules: {
            post_title: "required",
            post_content: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            post_title: "Please enter a title",
            post_content: "Please enter the content"
        }
    });

    comment_validator = $("#commentform").validate({
        rules: {
            comment: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            comment: "Please add a comment"
        }
    });

});
```

As none of the forms are being validated :/

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't noticed any mistake on your code. Is there any error or warning messages on your console? Could you paste it? Or maybe you did some html mistakes? Could you post log messages and html also?

Answer (score 0):

Found the bug :) seems I had done this `}, },`